# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Id of AspNetUsers(IdentityUser) in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-identity

I created A registration panel for Doctor, patient and Admin, when I'm trying to register or insert a data its gives error like this,

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUsers_Departments_DepartmentId". The conflict occurred in database "Hospitaldb", table "dbo.Departments", column 'Id'

The migration part:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetUsers",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        Discriminator = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(21)", maxLength: 21, nullable: false),
        UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
        PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
        TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
        LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
        LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
        AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
    
        // I Added This Line
        DepartmentId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);

        // I Added This Code Block
        table.ForeignKey(
        name: "FK_AspNetUsers_Departments_DepartmentId",
        column: x => x.DepartmentId,
        principalTable: "Departments",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
}
```

Department model class:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

DbInitializer which inherits from `IDbInitializer`:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    try
    {
        if (_context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
        {
            _context.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    if (!_roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(WebsiteRoles.Website_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
    {
        _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(WebsiteRoles.Website_Admin)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(WebsiteRoles.Website_Patient)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(WebsiteRoles.Website_Doctor)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "XYZ",
            Email = "xyz@gmail.com"
        }, "XYZ@123").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var Appuser = _context.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == "xyz@gmail.com");
        if (Appuser != null)
        {
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(Appuser, WebsiteRoles.Website_Admin).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Specialist { get; set; }
    public bool IsDoctor { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Payroll> Payrolls { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<PatientReport> PatientReports { get; set; }
}
```

`DoctorRegister.cs` file of `IdentityUser`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null) {
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = CreateUser();

        await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
        await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

        user.Name = Input.Name;
        user.Address = Input.Address;
        user.Nationality = Input.Nationality;
        user.DOB = Input.DOB;
        user.Gender = Input.Gender;
        user.IsDoctor = Input.IsDoctor;
        user.Specialist = Input.Specialist;
        ImageOpertaions image = new ImageOpertaions(_env);
        string filename = image.ImageUpload(Input.PictureUrl);
        user.PictureUrl = filename;

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, WebsiteRoles.Website_Doctor);

            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            //code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            //var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            //    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
            //    pageHandler: null,
            //    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
            //    protocol: Request.Scheme);

            //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
            //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page(); 
}
```

CreateUser method:

```
private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
{
    try
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
            $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
            $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
    }
}
```

When i debugging the code it throws an error after this line

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

I'm going to try to insert a row of data into the database using foreign key, but I get an error when I submitting data FOREIGN KEY constraint Id

One record already exists in database which I hardcoded

Comment: I found[ a similiar repo](https://github.com/MashuduK/E-NompiloPHC) which has some issues, and I can't reproduce your issue. If you want to fix the issue, it's better provide a sample for us investigateing. And please don't forget to hide the sensitive information.

Comment: Of course we can set a breakpoint and see if the DepartmentId exists in the Department table?

Comment: Can you confirm what the createUser() method is doing. Is it setting the department of the User. If the User does not have a department, make sure to have departmentId as NULL and not default which would be 0 and most likely would create a FOREIGNKEY constraint as the Department table might not have a row with Id as 0.

Comment: @SharathNS createUser creats a new user and insert a raw data with following details Name, Address, and so on..

Comment: Check which line threw an exception, set a breakpoint, and see why.

Comment: I checked and got an error on line 144, (DoctorRegister.cs file) var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
but its return the value correctly

Comment: Can you share the CreateUser method code, if it is possible OR while debugging check what is the value set in DepartmentId property of the user returned from CreateUSer method

Comment: While debugging, please check what value is sent as departmentId in user.Department.DepartmentId. Since it is an integer it would be set by default to 0 and there would not be any department with departmentID 0, and that is the reason you might be getting the foreignkey issue. You might have to make the ID property in department as Nullable

Comment: Then, I am also not sure what could be the issue. You will have to step into the CreateAsync() method while debugging and check each property of the User object that you are trying to insert. A foreign key reference issue means you are trying to update the child table with an ID which is not present in the parent table. Check if the departmentID you are passing in the user object is present in the Department table.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

I added this property to ApplicationUser:

```
public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
```

I added this to my AppDbContext.cs file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Configure the relationship between ApplicationUser and Department
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasOne(u => u.Department)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.DepartmentId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(u => u.DepartmentId)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
}
```

It creates the user and data is also shown in the SQL table.

I don't know how it implements a new DepartmentId property in ApplicationUser.

There are 3 id columns: ID (encrypted auto generated), DepartmentId (null) and DepartmentId1 (null). I don't know why.

Comment: Questions do not belong in answer posts, they belong in question posts. I have removed the text about your new question.